# Error when populating matrix

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, time-series

My question relates to populating the `mae` matrix below with the mean average error gotten by comparing `fcastmean` to the `testData`.

When running the for loop, the following error message comes up:

```
Error in mae[i,1:length(testIndexes)] <- (fcastmean - testData):
  replacement has length zero
```

In addition to this, there are some niggles that work, but which I feel need tidying up but am not sure how to. Namely the turning of `testData` and `trainData` into objects of class `mts`.

This is of course a secondary problem.

```
library("forecast")
library("vars")

#Create dataset for test purposes
d <- rnorm(70)
x <- rnorm(70)

dx <- cbind(d,x)
Data <- as.ts(dx)

k  <- 10 #Number of folds

mae <- matrix(NA,length(d)/k,k) #Create mae matrix

#Randomly shuffle the data
Data<-Data[sample(nrow(Data)),]

#Create k equally size folds
folds <- cut(seq(1,nrow(Data)),breaks=k,labels=FALSE)

#Perform k fold cross validation
for(i in 1:k){
  #Segement data by fold
  testIndexes <- which(folds==i,arr.ind=TRUE)
  testData <- Data[testIndexes, ]
  testData <- as.ts(testData)
  trainData <- Data[-testIndexes, ]
  trainData <- as.ts(trainData)

  #Use the test and train data partitions
  fit2 <- VAR(trainData, p = 2)                       
  fcast <- forecast(fit2, h = length(testIndexes))
  fcastmean <- do.call('cbind', fcast[['mean']])
  mae[i,1:length(testIndexes)] <- (fcastmean - testData)
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

**Edit**

I have partially resolved my above question by applying the following solution:

```
y <- length(d)/k

m1 <- matrix(NA, y, y)
m2 <- matrix(NA, y, y)
```

and in the for loop:

```
m1[i,1:length(testIndexes)] <- (testData[,1]) 
m2[i,1:length(testIndexes)] <- (fcastmean[,1])
```

followed by

```
mae <- m2-m1
```

After the loop.

However, while the matrix is created, the code only fills in `k` number of rows, rather than the number specified by `length(testIndexes).

Why is this?

**Edit 2**

It would appear the reason is that it only prints `i` iterations which is the same as `k`. However, the number of rows in the matrix needs to reflect the full forecast horizon, ie. `length(testIndexes)`.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: The two `mts` you are subtracting do not have the same index. For `k=1`, `testData` has `Start = 1` and `End = 7`, while `fcastmean` has `Start = 64` and `End = 70`.

I don't know if you need the indices, if not you could just force either of the two `mts` to the same index?

Comment: @kristang The idea is that the code splits the data into `k` number of fold of equal size, resulting in `k` different training and testing sets. The model is then run on each training set and used to predict the testing set for that iteration. The testing set for `k=8` should then have `Start = 2` and `End = 14`, and so on. That's the idea anyway.

Comment: I understand, but as far as I can see `mts` objects, when subtracted, will subtract by index. So if `fcastmean` and `testData` do not have the same indices, they cannot be subtracted.

Comment: @kristang is there any other way of getting the mean average error of between the forecast and the test data?

Comment: @kristang please see my edit.